# android - Criando um app para realizar impressões

Tags: android, impressora

Eu estive olhando o `Google Cloud Print` e parece ser a forma mais facil que tem, certo?

Porém a impressao seria para ficar em uma aplicação onde o usuário nao teria como ficar entrando na conta Google dele.

Visto isso, qual seria a melhor forma de realizar essas impressões?

Comment: Já tentou olhar esse https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html ?

Comment: já sim @LuanGabriel porem eu busco algo onde eu consigo conectar a impressora pelo IP dela